# Three20 TTThumbsViewController

Tags: iphone, three20, tabbar

I need to show some images in my app. So, I decided to use three20 and especially the TTThumbsViewController. i have tried to put it in my tabbar application, but it doesn't work.

What I have to do?? Is there another way to make an image gallery??

[Link to the project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2181964/progetto.zip)

P.S. Sorry for my English, i can't write but i understand very well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

follow below link :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer

Comment: raywenderlich had nice tutorial about thumbnail view and large view of image